# C++11 Allow inheritance only to certain classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

I have a base class that I'd like to prevent inheritance by most classes, but allow it for a handful of classes that I can hard code in. Is this possible in C++? Is it easier with C++11?

I thought perhaps I'd use the `final` argument, but that prevents any inheritance at all.

```
// This can be derived by anyone
class Base{
...
}

// This should only be derived by those I say can derive it
class Base2: public Base{
    protected:
         int SpecialVar;
}
```

The reason I want this is that some classes need to have access to `SpecialVar` while it doesn't make sense for the other classes. It still makes sense for all classes to have the functionality of `Base`.

Comment: You could require inheriting classes to implement one or more certain interfaces.

Comment: Is your base class abstract (or may it be abstract)?

Comment: I don't really want my base class to be abstract. It just defines one variable that some classes will need but not others.

Comment: You could forward-declare the derived classes, befriend them, and make all constructors private.

Comment: @dyp Duh, of course I could.

Comment: @dyp's comment is the only way to do this. My comment is that what you're trying to do it pointless and a waste of time and there is zero reason to do it, so don't.

Comment: I once had a similar problem, but in the end I realized that it was due to my design mistakes. Can I ask you what you are trying to prevent by disallowing other classes from inheriting Base2?

Comment: @KitsuneYMG Well, I disagree. There is a reason for me to do this.

Comment: @Jeremy it needs to be a very good reason. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Svalorzen I want some classes to have access to `SpecialVar` where it doesn't make sense for other variables to use it.

Comment: @Jeremy But then those other classes will not inherit from the base class. Going lengths to enforce that is not going to give you any real benefits aside from staining the code. It is not a responsibility of the Base2 class to know who is going to derive it.

Comment: @Svalorzen So why isn't dyp's suggestion a good idea? It seems like it would work fine and wouldn't mess things up too much.

Comment: @Jeremy It's not as if it wouldn't work. Let me put it this way: you cannot really mistake deriving from a class. If you are deriving from a class, it is because you think it is sensible to do so. If I was creating a new Number class, there shouldn't be a mechanism in std::string to prevent me from inheriting that because it makes no sense: I simply would not do it.

Comment: @Jeremy As for practical disadvantages: Having a class where you have to manually specify the allowed inheritors will make you recompile your whole program every time you need to add a new class, for whatever reason. Also, other people will not able to extend your work, if they ever feel the need to.

Answer (score 5):

```
class X 
{   
    private:
        X() {}

        friend class D;
};  

class D: public X
{   
};  

class Y: public X // will fail, because it can't access X::X()
{   
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of making your derived classes friends, another way (that may or may not make sense, depending on the concrete classes you're dealing with), is to nest them.

```
class Base {
    Base() { }
public:
    class Derived;
};

class Base::Derived : Base {
};

class CannotDerive : Base {
};

int main() {
    Base::Derived x; // ok
    CannotDerive y; // error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other possibility is with a private destructor (specially if `A` is an abstract class, since you don't need instances of `A`):

```
class A
{
  private:
     virtual ~A() = 0;
};

A::~A() {}

class B : public A // Compilation error: ~A() is private.
{};
```

However, if `B` is one of your classes with permission to inherit from A, make it friend of `A`:

```
class A
{
  private:
     friend class B;
     virtual ~A() = 0;
};

A::~A() {}

class B : public A // Fine.
{};
```